# Loading spinner before app rendered in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading, loading

I'm working on vue.js app and I want to add a loading spinner before the app component rendered.. like what Instagram doing when opening the Instagram page it shows their logo before showing the page contents .. I tried a lot of solutions but not working well!

any idea ? 
thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `v-cloak` attribute is probably what you want. See [this explanation](https://medium.com/vuejs-tips/v-cloak-45a05da28dc4)

Answer (score 0):

initially keep a state variable like showLoading : true

```
if(showLoading) {
      this.displayLoader();
       return;
 }
else {
    render (); //your main view
```

}

Comment: can you explain how and where doing this please?

Comment: it should be placed on your child component's render and after the success promise, you can set showLoading: false